# Spring Boot maven multimodule project - unit testing (application context)

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, spring-boot, applicationcontext

I am beginner with spring framework. I have a problem with configuring unit tests in spring boot, more precisely with loading spring context while running unit tests. I work with maven multimodule project (in team) and looking for the right solution to do this.
Part of my project structure is as follows:

- commons (module, packaging:jar, utils module)

  +--- src

  +--- pom.xml
- proposal (module, packaging:pom)

  - proposal-api (submodule: interfaces, dto, packaging:jar)
  - proposal-mapping (submodule: entities)
  - proposal-service (submodule: services, spring data repositories, dto - entity<->dto mappers, depends on proposal-api and proposal-mapping packaging:jar)

    +--- src

      +---main

        +--- java

          +---com.company.proposal.service

            +--- DeviceRepositoryService.java

            +--- 
    DeviceMapper.java

            +--- 
    ProposalRepositoryService.java

            +---
    ProposalMapper.java

            +--- 
    and much more classes...

      +--- test

        +--- java

          +---com.company.proposal.service

            +---
    DeviceRepositoryServiceTest.java

            +---
    ProposalRepositoryServiceTest.java

            +---
    ...

    +--- pom.xml
  - proposal-starter (submodule: autoconfiguration classes, packaging:jar)

    +--- src

      +---main

        +--- java

          +---com.company.proposal.configuration

            +--- ProposalAutoConfiguration.java

            +--- RemoteReportProcessorAutoConfiguration.java

            +--- other configuration classes...

        +---resources

          +---META-INF

            +--- spring.factories

          +---application.properties

    +--- pom.xml
- entry-point (module, packaging: pom)

  - entry-point-api (submodule, packaging: jar)
  - entry-point-service (submodule, packaging: jar)
  - entry-point-starter (submodule, packaging: war deployed on wildfly)
- other-modules ...
- pom.xml (root pom)

---

Example unit test written by me (DeviceRepositoryServiceTest.java):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DeviceRepositoryServiceTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @MockBean
    private DeviceRepository deviceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DeviceMapper deviceMapper;

    private DeviceRepositoryService deviceRepositoryService;

    private final String imei = "123456789123456";
    private final String producer = "samsung";
    private final String model = "s5";

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        deviceRepositoryService = new DeviceRepositoryService(deviceRepository, deviceMapper);
    }

    @org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public DeviceMapper deviceMapper() {
            return new DeviceMapperImpl();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test_should_create_device() {
        given(deviceRepository.findByImei(imei)).willReturn(null);
        when(deviceRepository.save(any(Device.class))).thenAnswer((Answer) invocation -> invocation.getArguments()[0]);
        DeviceSnapshot device = deviceRepositoryService.createOrFindDeviceByImei(imei, producer, model);
        assertThat(device.getImei()).isEqualTo(imei);
        assertThat(device.getProducer()).isEqualTo(producer);
        assertThat(device.getModel()).isEqualTo(model);
        verify(deviceRepository, times(1)).save(any(Device.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_should_return_device() {
        Device testDevice = createTestDevice();
        given(deviceRepository.findByImei(imei)).willReturn(testDevice);
        DeviceSnapshot actualDevice = deviceRepositoryService
                .createOrFindDeviceByImei(testDevice.getImei(), testDevice.getProducer(), testDevice.getModel());
        assertThat(actualDevice.getImei()).isEqualTo(testDevice.getImei());
        assertThat(actualDevice.getProducer()).isEqualTo(testDevice.getProducer());
        assertThat(actualDevice.getModel()).isEqualTo(testDevice.getModel());
        verify(deviceRepository, times(0)).save(any(Device.class));
        verify(deviceRepository, times(1)).findByImei(testDevice.getImei());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_should_find_device() {
        Device device = createTestDevice();
        given(deviceRepository.findOne(device.getId())).willReturn(device);
        DeviceSnapshot actualDevice = deviceRepositoryService.findDeviceById(device.getId());
        DeviceSnapshot expectedDevice = deviceMapper.toDeviceSnapshot(device);
        assertThat(actualDevice).isEqualTo(expectedDevice);
        verify(deviceRepository, times(1)).findOne(device.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_should_find_device_by_pparams() {
        Device device = createTestDevice();
        Long proposalId = 1L, providerConfigId = 2L;
        given(deviceRepository.findByProposalParams(proposalId, providerConfigId)).willReturn(device);
        DeviceSnapshot actualDevice = deviceRepositoryService.findDeviceByProposalParams(proposalId, providerConfigId);
        DeviceSnapshot expectedDevice = deviceMapper.toDeviceSnapshot(device);
        assertThat(actualDevice).isEqualTo(expectedDevice);
        verify(deviceRepository, times(1)).findByProposalParams(proposalId, providerConfigId);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_should_throw_not_found_1() {
        given(deviceRepository.findOne(anyLong())).willReturn(null);
        this.thrown.expect(DeviceNotFoundException.class);
        deviceRepositoryService.findDeviceById(1L);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_should_throw_not_found_2() {
        given(deviceRepository.findByProposalParams(anyLong(), anyLong())).willReturn(null);
        this.thrown.expect(DeviceNotFoundException.class);
        deviceRepositoryService.findDeviceByProposalParams(1L, 1L);
    }

    private Device createTestDevice() {
        return Device.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .imei(imei)
                .model(model)
                .producer(producer)
                .build();
    }
}
```

As you can see I use @TestConfiguration annotation to define context, but because class `DeviceRepositoryService` is quite simple - only 2 dependencies so context definition is also simple. I also have to test class `ProposalRepositoryService` which looks as follows in short:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class ProposalRepositoryService implements ProposalService {

    private final ProposalRepository proposalRepository;
    private final ProposalMapper proposalMapper;
    private final ProposalRepositoryProperties repositoryProperties;
    private final ImageProposalRepository imageProposalRepository;
    private final ProviderConfigService providerConfigService;
    ...
}
```

In above class is more dependencies and the thing is I don't want to write bunch of configuration code for every test (TestConfiguration annotation). Eg. If I add some dependency to some service I would have to change half of my unit tests classes, also a lot of code repeats itself. I have also example when unit test code is getting ugly because of configuration definition:

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class RemoteReportProcessorRepositoryServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private RemoteReportProcessorRepositoryService remoteReportProcessorRepositoryService;

    @TestConfiguration //here, I don't want to write bunch of configuration code for every test
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public RemoteReportProcessorRepositoryService remoteReportProcessorRepositoryService(RemoteReportMailService remoteReportMailService,
                                                                                             FtpsService ftpsService,
                                                                                             RemoteDailyReportProperties remoteDailyReportProperties,
                                                                                             RemoteMonthlyReportProperties remoteMonthlyReportProperties,
                                                                                             DeviceRepository deviceRepository,
                                                                                             ProposalRepository proposalRepository) {
            return new RemoteReportProcessorRepositoryService(ftpsService, remoteReportMailService, remoteDailyReportProperties, remoteMonthlyReportProperties, deviceRepository, proposalRepository);
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public FtpsManagerService ftpsManagerService(FTPSClient ftpsClient, MailService mailService, FtpsProperties ftpsProperties) {
            return new FtpsManagerService(ftpsClient, ftpsProperties, mailService);
        }

        @Bean
        public FTPSClient ftpsClient() {
            return new FTPSClient();
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public MailService mailService(MailProperties mailProperties, JavaMailSender javaMailSender, PgpProperties pgpProperties) {
            return new MailManagerService(mailProperties, javaMailSender, pgpProperties);
        }

        @Bean
        public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
            return new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public RemoteReportMailService remoteReportMailService(RemoteReportMailProperties remoteReportMailProperties,
                                                               JavaMailSender javaMailSender,
                                                               Session session,
                                                               PgpProperties pgpProperties) {
            return new RemoteReportMailManagerService(remoteReportMailProperties, javaMailSender, session, pgpProperties);
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public Session getJavaMailReceiver(RemoteReportMailProperties remoteReportMailProperties) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.imap.host", remoteReportMailProperties.getImapHost());
            properties.put("mail.imap.port", remoteReportMailProperties.getImapPort());
            properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
            properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", remoteReportMailProperties.getImapPort().toString());
            properties.put("mail.imap.debug", "true");
            properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*");
            return Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        }
    }
...
}
```

So, my question is how to configure spring context for unit testing in spring boot maven multimodule project the right way, without writing bunch of configuration code?
I also will be grateful for the links to the articles when is describe in detail how to deal with maven multimodule projects.

Comment: You can create a common parent class for similar Test cases which contains the configuration code.

Comment: Could you show any example? I could write one class (eg. in commons module) which holds all configuration code but that class would have to depends on all other modules (circular dependency).

Comment: Please try with the parent class approach, I don't think there would be any problem of circular dependency. I will try to post an example

Comment: So, could you give some example or link to example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading various articles and posts eg. [Is it OK to use SpringRunner in unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725024/is-it-ok-to-use-springrunner-in-unit-tests) I realized that I don't need the entire application context when running tests, instead I should mock bean dependencies using plain `@Mock` annotation if testing without even involving and loading spring application context (which is faster). However, If I need some slice of application context (eg. to automatically load test properties or just for integration tests)
then I use spring boot annotations prepared for that: `@WebMvcTest` `@JpaTest` `@SpringBootTest` and so on.

Examples:

Plain Mock Test (without involving spring):

```
public class UserServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository);
    }

    /* Some tests here */

}
```

Test with slice of spring context:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = DecisionProposalProperties.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        DecisionProposalRepositoryService.class,
        DecisionProposalMapperImpl.class
})
public class DecisionProposalRepositoryServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private DecisionProposalRepository decisionProposalRepository;

    @MockBean
    private CommentRepository commentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DecisionProposalRepositoryService decisionProposalRepositoryService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    /* Some tests here */

}
```

Data jpa test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class ImageProposalRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private ImageProposalRepository imageProposalRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindOne() throws Exception {
        ImageProposal imageProposal = ImageProposal.builder()
                .size(1024)
                .filePath("/test/file/path").build();
        entityManager.persist(imageProposal);
        ImageProposal foundImageProposal = imageProposalRepository.findOne(imageProposal.getId());
        assertThat(foundImageProposal).isEqualTo(imageProposal);
    }
}
```